# FF mouseleave/mouseenter events

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I write extension to FF and this part of the code does not work on earlier versions 6.0-8.0.
But on 12.0-13.0 versions everything works great. What is the reason?

```
        for(var i = 0; i < doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo').length; i++)
        {
            doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo')[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
            doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo')[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[1].style.visibility = "hidden";

            doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo')[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', 
                function(e) {
                    e.target.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
                    e.target.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].style.visibility = "hidden";
                }, false);
            doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo')[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', 
                function(e) { 
                    e.target.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
                    e.target.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].style.visibility = "visible";
                }, false);
        }
```

Comment: Nitpick: `doc.getElementsByClassName('repInfo')[i]...` used over and over again is bad for performance. Set it to a variable and work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) support was added with Firefox 10.

Comment: probably there is some similar?

Comment: Yes you have to write a function that uses mouseover and mouseout and determines if the element is still in the parent.